# Getting current username in utils.py django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am new to django, trying to create a number sequence field while loading the page, the combination of current datetime + current username + count(his posts on this month) + 1 . To achieve this I use **initial**.

forms.py:

```
  class PostForm(ModelForm): 
       post_no = forms.CharField(
        label='Post No',initial=getPostNo,
         widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'readonly': 'readonly',
            'placeholder':'Post No'

         })
```

in utils.py the definition of getPostNo:

```
def getPostNo:
    from .models import Posts
    m = datetime.now().month
    y = datetime.now().year
    tme = datetime.now().strftime("%d%m%Y")
    cnt = Posts.objects.filter(employee_id=1,post_date__month=m,post_date__year=y).count()+1 #here i need to filter using the current user id logged in . i gave 1 for testing
    return tme+str(cnt)+str(current username) //here i need current username
```

I couldn't pass the logged in userid to getPostNo from forms.py and also I can't get request.user in utils.py.

Please suggest the right way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple.
just have to call the initialize function getPostNo in the view itself.

```
post_form = PostForm(initial={'post_no':getPostNo(request.user)})
```

getPostNo:

```
def getPostNo(user):
    from .models import Posts
    m = datetime.now().month
    y = datetime.now().year
    tme = datetime.now().strftime("%d%m%Y")
    cnt = Posts.objects.filter(employee_id=user.pk,post_date__month=m,post_date__year=y).count()+1 
    
    return tme+str(cnt)+str(user.username)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use [`request.user`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User)
which gives the current instance or id of logged-in user and [`request.user.username`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.username) for username so:

```py
def getPostNo():
    from .models import Posts
    m = datetime.now().month
    y = datetime.now().year
    tme = datetime.now().strftime("%d%m%Y")
    cnt = Posts.objects.filter(employee_id=request.user,post_date__month=m,post_date__year=y).count()+1
    return tme+str(cnt)+str(request.user.username)
```

Make sure that the user logged-in.